# SharePoint designer 2010 loop

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm using sharePoint designer 2010.
I create difference workflows for difference list, 
How can I create Workflow loop?
I need to create loop inside a specific workflow that remind the manager (manager - name that Situated inside a list item) to insert some data to the list (data like dates, nams etc).

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box there is no option to create loops within a SharePoint workflow. What you'll need to do is:

- either have the workflow stop and restart itself. This will only work if your workflow includes a pause.
- or create two identical workflows that trigger each other

This was answered in a recent question but I can't find it right now...

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, you cannot loop through designer workflow. But if you need to start another workflow from with in a workflow refer this,

http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

Comment: I need to create loop inside a specific workflow that remind the manager (name that contianed in a list item) to fillin some data inside the item (e.g. dates, nams etc).

Comment: You can't with a single SharePoint Designer workflow.  You need to have one workflow call another.  If you want to be able to loop, you need to build your own action in Visual Studio or purchase a product like Nintex or K2.

Answer (score 0):

SPD Workflows have a habit of looping, you could set the workflow to run on update, and each iteration update something which will trigger the WF to fire again. Not a great solution but should work

Comment: I tried to update a list item with a value but it didn't trigger the same workflow , even with 'start workflow automatically when an item is changed' checked. And when I try to update this list item manually workflow gets triggered. any idea why workflow is not getting triggered from the same workflow