# For Loop on Sharepoint List in Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-list

Is there any way to run a for loop on a Sharepoint List in a Workflow on SharePoint Designer 2010?

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily straightforward, as there's no "Loop" action or "For Each" condition (in 2010 at least, SPD2013 has a "Loop" function according to the first source below), but there are ways to manually create loop workflows.

Here's a detailed, in-depth example using one list and many views, as well as InfoPath: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24589.build-a-loop-workflow-using-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Here's another technique, using three different lists: http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.com/2011/11/create-for-each-loop-for-workflows.html

Similar questions have also been asked in the following places:

- [SharePoint designer 2010 loop](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20686/sharepoint-designer-2010-loop?rq=1)
- [creation of loop in sharepoint designer 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83778/creation-of-loop-in-sharepoint-designer-2010?rq=1)