# How can I create a looping workflow in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, infopath, designer-workflow

I need to create a simple job management workflow in SharePoint 2010 that looks something like this:

[image]

The OOTB Three-state workflow would work perfectly, *except* I do not want emails sent to the initiator at each stage, only to Person A and Person B.

I am very new to SharePoint Designer 2013 and Visio 2013, and am relatively experienced with InfoPath. My site collection uses SharePoint 2010 workflows (despite being a SharePoint 2013 site collection). Any advice or direction would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Workflow Trigger to On Change.

- If "Task Status" is "Not Started" and Assigned To is Empty

  - Assign Task to "Approver"
  - Send Email
- Else If "Task Status" is Approved

  - Stop Workflow
- Else

  - Send email to "Approver"
  - Stop Workflow

When the "Approver" changes the status, it will fire off the workflow again.

Comment: So simple! I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily straightforward, as there's no "Loop" action or "For Each" condition (in 2010 at least, SPD2013 has a "Loop" function according to the first source below), but there are ways to manually create loop workflows.

Here's a detailed, in-depth example using one list and many views, as well as InfoPath: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24589.build-a-loop-workflow-using-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Here's another technique, using three different lists: http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.com/2011/11/create-for-each-loop-for-workflows.html

Similar questions have also been asked in the following places:

- [SharePoint designer 2010 loop](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20686/sharepoint-designer-2010-loop?rq=1)
- [creation of loop in sharepoint designer 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83778/creation-of-loop-in-sharepoint-designer-2010?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

For lopping workflow you need to use SharePoint 2013 workflow i.e., Stage workflow. so that infinite time u call any stage any time.

Refer link:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-workflow-942a5441

http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-goto-step.htm